# Is 'open' in for loop a safe method in python?

Tags: python

Will codes like this close the `f.txt` safely?

```py
for line in open('f.txt', 'r'):
    pass
```

It runs correctly, but I'm worrying that the opened file will not be closed safely.

Comment: No. You want the `with` statement. (Also, "closed safely" is relative. It *will* be closed automatically when the file object goes out of scope. But if you want to be sure it closes immediately you can use the with statement.)

Comment: Python _does_ close files when the file handle object is garbage-collected (i.e. when all references to it go out of scope), and for sure when the interpreter exits; but letting it do so is not very deterministic and is a bad practice.

Answer (score 3):

Best practice is to use like below:

```
with open(filename,'r') as file_obj:
    # Do stuff with file_obj here
```

This will make sure that your file gets closed once you come out of with block.

Answer (score 1):

It is good practice to use the `with` keyword when dealing with `file objects`. The advantage is that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes, even if an `exception` is raised at some point.

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
  read_data = f.read()
```

if you are not using `with` statement then you should call `f.close()`.If you don’t explicitly close a file, `Python’s garbage collector` will eventually destroy the object and close the open file for you, but the file may stay open for a while